# I'm using meteor run android-device but it's giving spawn error which is wired

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, ionic-framework

[image]

Here is output of meteor run android-device:

> meteor run android-device
>   [[[[[ ~/repo/socialize ]]]]]
>
> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.                               Building for web.browser                  - Babel compiling files:
>   client/lib/module/angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js
>   client/lib/module/aws-sdk.min.js [BABEL] Note: The code generator has
>   deoptimised the styling of "/client/lib/module/aws-sdk.min.js" as it
>   exceeds the max of "100KB".   client/lib/module/helpers.js
>   client/lib/app.js   client/controllers/appCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/cardsCtrl.js   client/controllers/chatCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/connectionsCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/eCardCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/forgetPassCtrle.js
>   client/controllers/groupsParentCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/homeCtrl.js   client/controllers/loginCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/myGroupsCtrl.js   client/controllers/profileCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/publicGroupsCtrl.js
>   client/controllers/recentCtrl.js   client/controllers/signUpCtrl.js
>   client/directives/autoFocus.js   client/directives/msdElastic.js
>   client/directives/resizeFooter.js   client/filters/calendar.js
>   client/filters/chatLinkFilter.js   client/filters/chatName.js
>   client/services/mockService.js   client/services/s3BucketService.js
>   collections/cards/cards.js
>   collections/cardsCategory/cardsCategory.js
>   collections/chats/chats.js   collections/circles/circles.js
>   collections/groups/groups.js   collections/messages/messages.js
>   collections/users/users.js   client/routes.js    Building for
>   web.cordova                  - Babel compiling files:    Building for
>   os.linux.x86_64              | Babel compiling files:
>   server/cards/permissions.js   server/cards/publications.js
>   server/cardsCategory/methods.js   server/cardsCategory/permissions.js 
>   server/cardsCategory/publications.js   server/cardsCategory/seed.js
>   server/chats/methods.js   server/chats/permissions.js
>   server/chats/publications.js   server/circles/methods.js
>   server/circles/permissions.js   server/circles/publications.js
>   server/groups/methods.js   server/groups/permissions.js
>   server/groups/publications.js   server/messages/methods.js
>   server/messages/permissions.js   server/messages/publications.js
>   server/users/methods.js   server/users/permissions.js
>   server/users/publications.js   server/users/seed.js
>                                                  WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to
>   connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the same
>   network, and that the
>            network configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
>   => Errors executing Cordova commands:
>
> While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:    >Error:
>   Command failed:
>   /home/haider/repo/socialize/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
>   --device
>   events.js:72
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event    ^
>   Error: spawn EACCES
>   at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)    at
>   ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)    at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)    at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
>                                                  ExitWithCode:1

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for the error message?

Comment: yeah i tired but i didn't get any solution.